# find patterns for two list of numbers and in r using a better solution

Tags: r

I'm working on this but not very satisfied with my solution. It is not very efficient on a larger file.

I have two list of numbers:

```
a <- as.numeric(c("12345678","2235689","56980"))
b <- as.numeric(c("123","1234","223","2235689","111","222","555","888","12345","8989"))
```

and I need to know whether any number from a START with any numbers in b.

So I wrote a function as below:

```
findpattern <- function(a,b){
  a_s<-c()
  b_s<-c()
  for (a1 in a){
    z<-sapply(b,function(x)(1 %in% (regexpr(x,a1))))
    if (TRUE %in% unique(z)){
      b1 <- b[z]
      a_s<- c(a_s,a1)
      b_s<- c(b_s,pplist(b1))
    }
  }
  res <- data.frame(a_find=a_s,b_associate=b_s)
  return (res)
}
```

so the result should be like:

```
> findpattern(a,b)
   a_find    b_associate
1 12345678 123,1234,12345
2  2235689    223,2235689
```

but I'm not happy with my solution as when b file come with more than 10k numbers it is taking quite some time to finish it...is there a better solution for this?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Why convert to numeric? `grep` and regexes are kinda designed for character strings

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the data set I have is numeric...so I kinda make it numeric while making examples..

Comment: @nico I use it to make it one character when I have something like c("a","b"), turn to "a,b"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
result <- sapply(paste0('^', b), grepl, x=a)
rownames(result) <- a
#           ^123 ^1234  ^223 ^2235689  ^111  ^222  ^555  ^888 ^12345 ^8989
# 12345678  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE
# 2235689  FALSE FALSE  TRUE     TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE
# 56980    FALSE FALSE FALSE    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE
```

To get this in a format similar to your example result:

```
result.l <- apply(result, 1, function(row) b[row])
# $`12345678`
# [1]   123  1234 12345
# 
# $`2235689`
# [1]     223 2235689
# 
# $`56980`
# numeric(0)
```

I recommend using this over the format you show in your question, which is non-standard.

Or this, which looks like your desired result, but has a standard structure.

```
stack(lapply(result.l, paste, collapse=','))
#           values      ind
# 1 123,1234,12345 12345678
# 2    223,2235689  2235689
# 3                   56980
```

Comment: thanks for the quick solution. It does take much faster than my current one, but I'm having a hard time convert it efficiently to the format I want (the last result in my question). I have over 20K combinations in b, it is taking me a long time to convert it in a pretty format...

Comment: @linp then maybe you should rethink the need to produce such a detailed output.  What exactly are you trying to achieve (as opposed to 'how can I make this code work')?